# Null Reference Exception In LINQ to SQL DataContext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext, nullreferenceexception

I have a Null Reference Exception Caused by this code:

```
var recentOrderers = (from p in db.CMS
            where p.ODR_DATE > DateTime.Today - new TimeSpan(60, 0, 0, 0)
            select p.SOLDNUM).Distinct();
result = (from p in db.CMS
             where p.ORDER_ST2 == "SH" &&
                   p.ODR_DATE > DateTime.Today - new TimeSpan(365, 0, 0, 0) &&
                   p.ODR_DATE < DateTime.Today - new TimeSpan(60, 0, 0, 0) &&
                   !(recentOrderers.Contains(p.SOLDNUM))/**/
             select p.SOLDNUM).Distinct().Count();
```

result is of double type.  When I comment out:

```
!(recentOrderers.Contains(p.SOLDNUM))
```

The code runs fine.  I have verified that recentOrderers is not null, and when I run:

```
if(recentOrderes.Contains(0)) return;
```

Execution follows this path and returns.  Not sure what is going on, since I use similar code above it:

```
var m = (from p in db.CMS where p.ORDER_ST2 == "SH" select p.SOLDNUM).Distinct();
            double result = (from p in db.CUST
                        join r in db.DEMGRAPH on p.CUSTNUM equals r.CUSTNUM
                        where p.CTYPE3 == "cmh" && !(m.Contains(p.CUSTNUM)) &&
                              r.ColNEWMEMBERDAT.Value.Year > 1900
                        select p.CUSTNUM).Distinct().Count();
```

which also runs flawlessly. After noting the similarity, can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like? (I'm assuming this is LINQ to SQL or LINQ to Entities.)

Comment: Jon:  is this a case of lazy execution of the SQL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with Linq, but could it be that .Distinct() returns null if there are no matching results?

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicite get data from the first query by converting to a list object (actually: executing it using .ToList()) then use in comparison.

```
var recentOrderers = (from p in db.CMS
            where p.ODR_DATE > DateTime.Today - new TimeSpan(60, 0, 0, 0)
            select p.SOLDNUM).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: That works!  Though I still don't understand the difference.  Especially since it works in one section and not the next.

Comment: Because in your example your first query is a type of IQueryable which is not a real value itself - it is just a query definition.
And it is not good idea to treat query definition as data ;-)
Try to avoid 'var' and use concrete types in the future to avoid such a problems.

Comment: Use of var has nothing to do with this.  It's still strongly typed.